# CSS Selection of external SVG Path when hovering

Tags: css, svg, selector

```
<div class="subModuleBtn">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="calendar.svg"></object>
    <div class="subModuleBtnText">Submenu1</div>
</div>
```

The object and div are presented side to side to achieve ICON+Text look of a button

The code of SVG (I have included the CSS file) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="../../css/mainStyle.css"?>
<svg...>
    <path......./>
</g>
</svg>
```

How can I, when hovering over .subModuleBtn, alter SVG properties and .subModuleBtn properties simultaneously?
I have achieved to select the path (any path) from my external css with path { }. But that's it. Cannot select a path that is descendant of .subModuleBtn.

Comment: You can not modify the styling of an SVG that is embedded via `object` (or `img`, or as a background-image) The SVG needs to be _directly_ embedded into the HTML for this to work. https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#the-problem-with-both-img-and-background-image

Comment: I believe this is not true I have included the css file reference to the svg itself and I have already achieved to select the path of the svg with path { }.

Comment: Achieved to select it _from where_? If you are referring to the stylesheet you embedded into the SVG itself - of course _that_ works. But you will not be able to react to a hover on the outside HTML element `.subModuleBtn` from there.

Comment: Oh, I see.(By the way that stylesheet is the same I am using on my main page). Sorry to extend this question: "So I will have to use the same svg's inline over and over again to all my html pages in order to be able to affect their CSS. That is correct?

Comment: Yes, if you want to influence elements inside the SVG from your _page’s_ stylesheet, then those SVG need to be inline. But you will not have to _repeat_ the full same SVG over and over again, you can use the `use` element to display the same SVG in multiple places. https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-with-external-reference-take-2/

Comment: Thanks for all the help!